# How to display all the contents of a category in pyrocms page type

Tags: php, pyrocms

I am working on a Portfolio module with PyroCMS I am stuck in the following point and got no helpful answer so far on the CMS's forum :

I am having a Categories stream, which have been assigned some Projects against them.

So, I am managing to loop and display the title entries from the Categories stream within the appropriate Page Type, using the following "`pattern`":

```
{{ streams:cycle stream="categories" }}

{{ entries }} {{ id }} {{ /entries }}

{{ /streams:cycle }}
```

at the moment, unsuccessfully. Note that I have assigned the Categories stream to the specific Page Type, when I have created it.

I have tested  `{{ total }}` and it also `returns 0`.

I do not consider myself as completely familiar with `Streams and Page Types`, therefore any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Can you verify that there are entries in the stream?  In your admin navigate to Content > Streams > Click the Entries button on your categories stream. Also verify the stream slug is categories.

Comment: There is no "Streams" option under my Content menu.
Can I ask if the above syntax is available through PyroStreams?
If so, I am not using PyroStreams. It is a manual Streams implementation via its API.

Comment: I believe they tag you are using is available outside pyrostream but you need to be on version 2.2, are you still on version 2.1? I could be wrong on this as I just started using pyrocms with version 2.2

Comment: I am already using version 2.2, Patcouch22.

Still don't get anything, though. Any assumptions ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into a bit more your syntax is correct. However, like to speculated you will need pyrostreams in order use the stream tags.  The other way you could do this would be to write a custom plugin to give you the data you need.

The following post might give you some ideas on how to accomplish what you want with a plugin: https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/20253/looping-certain-data-in-plugins

Comment: I thought that there would be a more straight forward way, to retrieve the entries, rather than deploying my own plugin.

Appreciate your help, Patcouch22.